# How do I do this in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

In the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0qblk1BQrI) the guy was able to insert functions and classes by pressing some buttons. How do I set up my Emacs to do that? Did he just use auto insert mode or something?

Comment: Did you try the *c++ mode for emacs* ??

Comment: Doesn't emacs go into c++ mode by default? I don't get the features that he has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet), [skeletons](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode) or several other [template](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryTemplates) mechanisms for Emacs.

Comment: Those look really powerful. Do you know which one the guy in the video uses?

Comment: @Mark : Sorry I am not sure. The video description says _magic.el_, but I couldn't find the extension in a quick search.

Answer (score 5):

As suvayu indicated, the guy in that video is mostly using various template mechanisms in Emacs (this is actually not that impressive). If you want your mind to really be blown, have a look at Marco Barringer's [SLIME video](http://common-lisp.net/project/movies/movies/slime.mov). In it, he demos how to use the [Common Lisp SLIME mode](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/) in Emacs. Along the way, he shows how an expert Emacs user effectively utilizes Emacs to write code. First, just watch the movie. Then, if you want to know more details about what he's doing, read [Peter Christensen's transcript](http://www.pchristensen.com/blog/articles/reference-for-the-slimelispemacs-screencast/) of the movie (I wrote a [blog entry](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/050728.html) just after the movie came out with comments from a number of good lisp programmers who had seen the movie). Once you've seen the movie and can understand what is happening in it, attempt to adopt some of the techniques demonstrated in that video using your preferred programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look onto [SRecode module](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/srecode.shtml) in [CEDET package](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) - it allows to implement context-sensitive templates (for example, some are available only inside class, etc.), and there are some for elisp, c++, java, etc.